# Why does YouTube show some videos with blank thumbnail?

Tags: youtube

Here is the YouTube video that is still up, but its thumbnail
is **blank as if the video has been removed**:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQ8y6-7-fbY

[image]

Why does YouTube show some videos with blank thumbnail?